Edit bookmark URL from the star bookmark menu?
I can't do it. I followed this guide, but I can't do it. Has this code stopped working?
    /* Add option to edit bookmark URLs under blue star menu */
#editBMPanel_locationRow, #editBMPanel_keywordRow {
  visibility: visible !important;
}

Edit bookmark URL from the Edit bookmark menu?
Why are these two userChrome.css files incompatible?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It looks like they have been changed to classes for the rows and there is an id for the field. Also there is a hidden attribute on the HTML so you'll have to add display: block !important; as well. This is what you want:
/* Location field */
#editBMPanel_locationField, .editBMPanel_locationRow {
  visibility: visible !important;
  display: block !important;
}

/* Keyword field */
#editBMPanel_keywordField, .editBMPanel_keywordRow {
  visibility: visible !important;
  display: block !important;
}

